# OS X get process's memory programmatically

Tags: c++, macos, memory

I am trying to get the memory used by another process. From what I've read it seems like I need to use `mach_vm_regeion`. I found some code on a random forum and tried compiling to make sure I understood how it was working, but I get this error.

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'mach_vm_region'
      kret = mach_vm_region(task, &address, &size, VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO, (vm_regio...
             ^
1 error generated.
```

I am on OS X 10.11.2 compiling using `clang++ --std=c++11 file.cpp`.

`clang --version` returns

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: http://www.sagenb.org/src/misc/darwin_memory_usage.c    did you use the correct includes?

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to add a code snippet. I believe I have all the appropriate includes. Here it is http://pastie.org/10644474

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have the correct includes. I find that

```
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_vm.h>
```

works. You also need to change: `vm_size_t size` to `mach_vm_size_t size`, which is the type the function expects. Then it compiles and works as expected (when run as root, as the comment suggests).